# How to import the module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

I'm having the following project structure

[image]

In the file task_functions.py, I want to import the function defined in utility_functions.py and this is what I have in the files

task_functions.py

```
from utility.utility_functions import utility_func

def task_function() -> bool:
    print(r'I\'m calling utility function now')
    utility_func()
```

utility_functions.py

```
def utility_func() -> bool:
    print('This is my utility function')
```

When I have the following launch.json, I was able to run it in debug mode.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"},
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true
    }
]
```

}

However, if I run the file task_function.py in 'Run' mode in vscode, it always throws the exception "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utility'". I tried to print out the directory when run the script, it points to the root directory, that is, "DIRECTORY_IMPORT". I also tried to change the current directory using os.chdir(..) to move one directory up or other directory, it still didn't work. I guess I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here. What should be the right way to do the import? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use an improper way to import the module from another directory. You received that error because the Python interpreter looks at the current directory only. As your module is located in another directory, you can see if [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/) can help.

Comment: Answer gives a hint but not the exact answer to the question